# What it means to have CSS classes in this way: .class1.class2?

Tags: css

I've been using the [Zurb Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/)

In their CSS files I saw something I haven't seen before:

```
.blue.button:hover, .blue.button:focus {
background-color: #0192DD;
}
.nice.blue.button {
border: 1px solid #0593DC;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
background-color: #0192DD;
color: white;
}
.blue.button {
background-color: #00A6FC;
}
```

For instance, I know very well what `.blue .button` does but I have no idea what `.blue.button` does. Can Anyone explain this to me?

Comment: See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Answer (score 1):

Means an element with all these classes (e.g. `<button class="blue button>`).

Comment: Only elements that have these two classes: `blue button`? so an element with only the class `blue` or only the class `button` don't apply?

Comment: Correct. I should have emphasized the word **all**. To provide alternatives, you separate them by commas: `.blue, .button` - **either** "blue" **or** "button" **or** both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`.blue.button` applies to an element that has both the class `blue` and `button`,
like `<p class="blue button">`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that this style will be applied only in case when both classes will be on the element.

```
<a href="#" class="blue button">Link</a> // will work
<a href="#" class="button">Link</a> // will not work
<a href="#" class="blue">Link</a> // will not work
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Basically the rule only applies to elements which have both of the classes.

When you have `.class1, .class2`, the rule applies to both, elements having `class1` and elements having `class2`. `.class1.class2` means it only applies to an element having `class="class1 class2"`. `.class1 .class2` means it applies to an element having `class2` which is arbitarily nested inside an element with `class1`.

For further reading: [Class selectors in CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

Comment: No, `.class1 .class2` means it applies to `class2` elements inside `class1` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item selected"></div>
<div class="notitem selected"></div>
```

You can then make all items red
.item(color:red)

But only selected items red/bold
.item.selected{font-weight:bold}

while not doing anything to other selected things...

Hope it makes sense